# Modifying a copy of List<T> and comparing to the original List<T>

Tags: c#, list, datagridview

I have a List(T) populated from a sql stored procedure.

```
    dailyReqsList = ShipDB.GetDailyReqs(loadValues);
```

This list populates a datagridview.

```
dgvDailyReqs.DataSource = dailyReqsList;
dgvDailyReqs.Refresh();
CurrencyManager cm = 
CurrencyManager)(dgvDailyReqs.BindingContext[dailyReqsList]);
cm.Refresh();
```

If you click on a particular cell, it will open a form and pull data relative to that row.  On that form you can select items from a listbox that may refer to one or more items(rows) from the datagridview.  If you check a box it will return you to the datagridview and subtract an amount determined from the listbox.  This all works great – on the first pass.  When you do it a second time, to add another box, it will subtract the new data and the old data again.  Here is the code listed below.

```
orderDeduct = ShipDB.GetDeduction(dailyReq);
List<ItemMaster> deductedReq = new List<ItemMaster>(dailyReqsList);

if (deductedReq[v].Balance == dailyReqsList[v].Balance)
{
    if (orderDeduct.QtyShipped > 0)
    {
        if (deductedReq[v].QtyReqDay1 > 0)
        {
            if (orderDeduct.QtyShipped >= DeductedReq[v].QtyReqDay1)
            {
                orderDeduct.QtyShipped = orderDeduct.QtyShipped – 
                deductedReq[v].QtyReqDay1;
                deductedReq[v].QtyReqDay1 = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                deductedReq[v].QtyReqDay1 = deductedReqv].QtyReqDay1 
                - orderDeduct.QtyShipped;
                orderDeduct.QtyShipped = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    …
    deductedReq[v].Balance = deductedReq[v].QtyOnHand
        - deductedReq[v].QtyCommitted 
        + deductedReq[v].QtyReqDay1 + deductedReq[v].QtyReqDay2
        + deductedReq[v].QtyReqDay3 + deductedReq[v].QtyReqDay4
    …
}
```

The code follows through seven days and like I stated above, works great on the first pass.  The problem is when you engage the method again, I thought the line

```
List<ItemMaster> deductedReq = new List<ItemMaster>(dailyReqsList);
```

Would make a copy of the original list and I would use that as the running total list that I could compare against the original to bypass if they were not equal.  This is the reason for the line

```
if (deductedReq[v].Balance == dailyReqsList[v].Balance)
```

I assumed that would check the balance from the original list (dailyReqsList) to that of the deductedReq list.  Any assistance pointing me in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: You are right to say that your line `List<ItemMaster> deductedReq = new List<ItemMaster>(dailyReqsList);` will create new list with the same elements, but it actually points to the same element... but since you got data from Database, you could probably update the database with new data such that when you query it again, the value would have been changed.

Comment: As already stated by Ian, You made a Shallow Copy of your collection, so yes, you have a new collection with the same elements but the elements are the same present in the other collection. To create a copy of the content of the collection you must Clone the elements. Usually I would create a Clone Method in the ItemMaster class to duplicate its content, and in this case a method Clone to duplicate the collection and its elements, or if possible, create a Specific collection derived from List<T> for my data and put the Clone of the entire collection inside the collection class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Sabrina stated, I needed change the ItemMaster class to perform a deep copy rather than a shallow copy.

I made the following changes to it.

```
public ItemMaster ShallowCopy()
{
    return (ItemMaster)this.MemberwiseClone();
}
```

and

```
public ItemMaster DeepCopy()
{
    ItemMaster clonedItem = (ItemMaster)this.MemberwiseClone();

    clonedItem.Balance = Balance;
    clonedItem.QuantityOnHand = QuantityOnHand;
    clonedItem.QuantityCommitted = QuantityCommitted;
    clonedItem.QuantityAvailable = QuantityAvailable;
    clonedItem.QtyReqDay1 = QtyReqDay1;
    clonedItem.QtyReqDay2 = QtyReqDay2;
    clonedItem.QtyReqDay3 = QtyReqDay3;
    clonedItem.QtyReqDay4 = QtyReqDay4;
    clonedItem.QtyReqDay5 = QtyReqDay5;
    clonedItem.QtyReqDay6 = QtyReqDay6;
    clonedItem.QtyReqDay7 = QtyReqDay7;

    return clonedItem; 
}
```

I then changed the line

```
List<ItemMaster> deductedReq = new List<ItemMaster>(dailyReqsList);
```

to

```
deductedReq = dailyReqList.ConvertAll(ItemMaster => ItemMaster.DeepCopy());
```

and called the CalculateDeductions(dailyReqList[v])  method.

Also, I changed the scope of the List(deductedReq) - it was local to that method and now its form wide.  This was done since it's created in one method and updated in another.

I hope this explanation helps clarify the issue I had and how it was fixed.